# How to copy an ActiveX command button to another sheet and keep the name of the button

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried the code below to copy an ActiveX command button from one sheet and paste it into another:

```
Sheets("SRC").HasACustomName.Copy
Sheets("TRGT").Range("O1").PasteSpecial
```

I've also tried:

```
Sheets("SRC").Shapes("hasACustomName").Copy 
Sheets("TRGT").Range("O1").Select 
Sheets("TRGT").Paste
```

But the problem I have with both of these is that they rename the Command button from hasACustomName to CommandButtonX.

Can you figure out an alternative method for pasting a command button from one sheet to another that let's me retain the original name of the Command button?

Comment: @mehow: Um... so you post your answer both places?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett long story short - the questions were different to start off with then they ended up being the same thing in the end so i recopied the answer and i think ive flagged it for merging and if i didnt feel free to do that

Comment: +1  to JFC's comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## ActiveX

You can copy an ActiveX Control from one sheet to another with the below code.

Note: *you cannot have two objects of the same name on one spreadsheet.*

```
Sub CopyActiveX()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim x As OLEObject, y As OLEObject
    Set x = Sheets("SRC").OLEObjects("HasCustomName")
    Set y = x.Duplicate
    Dim xName As String
    xName = x.Name
    y.Cut
    With Sheets("TRGT")
        .Paste
        .OLEObjects(.OLEObjects.Count).Name = xName
        .Activate
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

## Form Control

To copy a button from one sheet to another preventing the automatic name change use the below code. Excel by default gives a new name to a copied button (*even on a different sheet*) so you have to rename it to match the name of the button youre copying.

Use `CopyButton()` sub to achieve it. There are 4 required parameters

- `from` - sheet name to copy the button from
- `btnName` - the name of the control you want to copy
- `toWorksheet` - target worksheet
- `rng` - target range to associate with the button

---

```
Sub CopyPasteButton()
    CopyButton "SRC", "Button 1", "TRGT", "B10"
End Sub

Private Sub CopyButton(from As String, btnName As String, toWorksheet As String, rng As String)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets(from).Shapes(btnName).Copy
    Sheets(toWorksheet).Activate
    Sheets(toWorksheet).range(rng).Select
    Sheets(toWorksheet).Paste
    Selection.ShapeRange.Name = btnName
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```